# Find the best round-trip ticket combinations

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, linear-programming

## Problem

A user wants to find the `n` cheapest combinations of an outward and inward flight in between a flexible time-window.

I have the given user-variables:

- `Dd` = earliest possible departure-day to start the trip
- `Rd` = latest possible return-day to end the trip
- `Min` = minimum amount of days between departure and return
- `Max` = maximum amount of days between departure and return

For both inward and outward I have separate lists of journeys for each day (from `Dd` to `Rd`). Each day-list contains all suitable and possible journeys on that specific day.

The result should be displayed as an ordered list by price.

## My approach

I can only think of the very simple approach of resolving each day-list to the cheapest journey on that day (since time is not relevant), then building up two binary trees (for inward and outward) with the date as node and price as value. Then iterating through the outward tree and look up the inward journeys (with `Min` to `Max` as offset) and put each combination into a sorted list.

## How to optimize?

I'm pretty sure my solution offers space for optimizations. I did some research that leads me to linear programming, but I have problems formulating this problem... maybe other algorithms or approaches suiting this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could find all journeys that fit the criteria and sort them by cost in something like this pseudo-python:

```
for out in (all departures between Dd and Rd):
    for ret in (all returns betweem out and Rd):
        possibles.add((out, ret))
time_pruned = [journey for journey in possibles 
               if stay_between(Min, Max, journey)]
order_by_cost = sorted(time_pruned, key=cost_function)
```